# WP8.1 MS-Ads "Invalid value for parameter (Name: w)"

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ads

Hi i'm using Microsoft Advertising in Windows Phone 8.1 and am getting the error: "Invalid value for parameter (Name: w)".  ONLY when uploading a ".appx" file after building a publishing version.  When I run in debug or release everything works great but not after I do a build for publishing and test the final ".appx" file.

The error in question is only suppose to show if the "width" of the Ad is not being set but it is.  Furthermore because it works in normal builds just not the final one this makes no sense at all.

My software is: Windows 8.1, Visual Studios 2013 Update 5 RC, Windows Phone 8.1 (multiple devices tested).  Is there some kind of code stripping or options I can try that might be effecting final builds?  Or is there a bug in VS2013 Update5 RC?

Ads are being created pragmatically setting the values below:

```
adControl = new AdControl();
adControl.IsAutoRefreshEnabled = true;
adControl.IsEngagedChanged += adControl_IsEngagedChanged;
adControl.AdRefreshed += adControl_AdRefreshed;
adControl.ErrorOccurred += adControl_ErrorOccurred;
adControl.ApplicationId = "xxxxx";
adControl.AdUnitId = "xxxxx";
adControl.Width = 480;
adControl.Height = 80;
adControl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
adControl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
WinRTPlugin.AdGrid.Children.Add(adControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this value needed to be set: "adControl.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 98);"